# React JSX Onclick Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to coding I want to display my Form.jsx to my AddWord.jsx Form.jsx is a form Addword.jsx is a button in Addword.js onclick i have to display Form.jsx
help me

```
//This is my code
import React from 'react'
import App from '../App'
import Form from './Form'

function AddWords() {
    return (
        <div>
           <button type="button" onclick="">Click Me!</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddWords
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code a little so that you can have a reusable button component, and a parent component (`App`) where both the form and the button sit.

In this example form visibility is stored in `App` state (using [the `useState` React hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)) and a button handler is passed down to the button in its props to toggle that state `true`/`false` which shows/hides the form.

```js
// This example uses the `useState` hook for
// storing state
const { useState, Fragment } = React;

// A simple form component
function Form() {
  return <div>Form</div>;
}

// AddWords is now a reusable button component
// that accepts a button handler function, and some text
// for the button. When `onClick` (don't forget that
// it's camelCase) is called it calls the handler
// that was passed down to it.
function Button({ handleButton, text }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleButton}
      >
        {text}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {

  // Initialise the state to false. `isFormVisible` is the
  // variable that holds the state, `setFormVisible` is the
  // function that allows us to update it.
  const [ isFormVisible, setFormVisible ] = useState(false);
    
  // The handler that we pass to the button. It toggles
  // the `isFormVisible` state from `true` to `false`, or
   // `false` to `true.
  function toggleForm() {
    setFormVisible((visible) => !visible);
  }
  
  // We return a fragment wrapping our child
  // Form and Button components. Note that we're
  // passing the toggleForm function and text down as
  // Button props.
  // The form is only visible if `isFormVisible` is true.
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Button
        handleButton={toggleForm}
        text="Click me!"
      />
      {isFormVisible && <Form />}
    </Fragment>
  );
  
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Did you mean `import { useState, Fragment } from 'React';` ?

Comment: @dev_junwen, I've done it that way to get the code to work in the snippet, but normally that's what you'd do, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You may convert your functional component to class component and your code will be more precise and readable. Here I have used **`state`** which is bind with this react app, if any change react dom element will render based on change.

One more thing I want mention here is **`{this.state.isVisible && <Form />}`**, in javascript if 1st part returns truthy the next part will execute otherwise not, so here if **`this.state.isVisible`** = true only then **`Form`** will be visible

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";

class AddWords extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>AddWords</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
        {this.state.isVisible && <Form />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddWords;
```